# Regular Expression to extract multiple parts when some string parts are absent

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a regular expression that will capture several sections of a string. This is the expression I have created:

```
([0-9]{6}[-*][0-9xX]{7}).*([0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}).*([FPTSUCD])=?([01][*-])
```

The string that this runs against can appear in two different styles:

```
@ 141803-6310114 @3-0-2 T0-jL
```

Or

```
]@0-7-4 C1-vU
```

When I use the first string I get all the parts I need.

```
141803-6310114
3-0-2
T
0-
```

When I use the second string I get no matches. This second sting is basically the same as the first but without this part “141803-6310114”. I would like the expression to work with both strings but for the number sequence to be optional. Can anyone advise on what the expression should look like to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the parts in both cases:

```
(?:(\d{6}[-*][\dxX]{7}))?[^\d]*(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}) ([FPTSUCD])=?([01][*-])
```

Made the first group optional (?) and changed the "eat all" between the first two groups to a "eat all non digits" + other clean up to make it more readable (at least to me ;)).

Regards

Comment: This doesn’t quite work as the “@” may or may not appear in either string. I didn’t show all the data surrounding these strings as it changes and I have no control over it.

Comment: This now seems to do what I need. Many thanks for that.